# JMeter - refering User Defined Variable in Http POST body

Tags: jmeter

Can someone tell me how to access user defined variable inside an attached file of the HTTP Sampler?

**What I did:**
created an HTTP Requset Sampler (method POST);
created a variable `myvar` which is a JMeter 'Random Variable'.

**Problem:**
When I refer `${myvar}` to populate an Http header it works but when I use it inside the file I am sending as the POST body it is not replaced but sent as it is `${myvar}`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**1.** As per reference [18.1.2 HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

> **Parameter Handling:**
>   
>  
>   For the POST and PUT method, if there is no file to send, and the name(s) of the parameter(s) are omitted, **then
>   the body is created by concatenating all the value(s) of the
>   parameters.** This allows arbitrary bodies to be sent. The values are
>   encoded if the encoding flag is set (versions of JMeter after 2.3).

So if you want to solve your problem with only *standard* HTTP Sampler functionality your have to use no file for your POST request and set ${myvar} as request param without name, as per above.

Since this approach seems not very applicable in your case, you may try also the following.

**2.** Rewrite your file to set ${myvar} to actual value before using in HTTP Request.

You can do this using either [BSF PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_PreProcessor) / [BeanShell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) - both attached *directly to* the "target" HTTP Request - or [BSF Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_Sampler) / [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) - these should be placed *before* the "target" HTTP Request.

The code for the re-writing sampler may be like the following (beanshell):

```java
// parsing params passed to script
String [] params = Parameters.split(",");

// setting values from params
String postFile = params[0];
String myVarValue = params[1];

StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(project.getProperty("basedir") +          
    System.getProperty("file.separator") + postFile));

char[] buf = new char[1024];
int numRead = 0;
while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    data.append(buf, 0, numRead);
}
in.close();

// re-writting ${myvar} with actual value
String temp = data.toString().replaceAll("\\$\\{myvar\\}", myVarValue);

Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(project.getProperty("basedir") + 
    System.getProperty("file.separator") + postFile));
out.write(temp);
out.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Alies, for the response. But I got this resolved. Follow this JMeter JIRA issue https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15468.  "the HTTP Sampler GUI has been enhanced to include a raw post body (will be in 2.6, due very soon").  For now I got the HTTP sampler jar from the nightly builds of the JMeter and replaced my local one with this and it works great. There is a text area to paste the Http POST body which can include any variables as well.

Comment: @crs Ok. Just FYI: [Jmeter 2.6](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) released yet in the early days of the February.